# Does "inverting" distribute over addition? Is $(f(x)+g(x))^{-1} = f^{-1}(x) + g^{-1}(x)$ always true?

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

Does "inverting" distribute over addition? Is this equation always true, for any functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$? $$(f(x)+g(x))^{-1} = f^{-1}(x) + g^{-1}(x)$$

By $^{-1}$ I mean inverse of the function, not $1$ divided by it.

edit... the answer is no. please see my other question instead [Which functions make it true? $(f(x)+g(x))^{-1} = f^{-1}(x) + g^{-1}(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640601/which-functions-make-it-true-fxgx-1-f-1x-g-1x)

Comment: You should rather write $(f+g)^{-1}(x)$. Did you try an example?

Comment: No, of course it's not always true. It is hardly ever true. Did you try it on any functions at all?

Comment: what functions is it true for?

Comment: ok it doesnt work for $x$ and doesnt work for $x^2$ and doesnt work for $\sin x$

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work because inverse of $2x$ is $x/2$ not $2x$

Comment: That's better! Now the real question is: do there exist _any_ invertible functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f+g$ is also invertible and $(f+g)^{-1}=f^{-1}+g^{-1}$? Just to be clear, I don't know the answer myself.

Comment: I made it one question another post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640601/which-functions-make-it-true-fxgx-1-f-1x-g-1x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not hold, take for example $f(x)=g(x)=x$.

Comment: thank you. can you look at my other question too? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640601/which-functions-make-it-true-fxgx-1-f-1x-g-1x it is the same topic , same equation