# Which functions make it true? $(f(x)+g(x))^{-1} = f^{-1}(x) + g^{-1}(x)$

Tags: functions, inverse, functional-equations, inverse-function

Sum of inverses is inverse of sum:

$$(f(x)+g(x))^{-1} = f^{-1}(x) + g^{-1}(x)$$

It is not true for all functions.

For example $x$ is its own function inverse, but $x+x = 2x$ but the inverse is $x/2$ not $2x$.

Which functions make it true?

$$(f(x)+g(x))^{-1} = f^{-1}(x) + g^{-1}(x)$$

By $^{-1}$ I mean inverse of the function, not $1$ divided by it.

Comment: I doubt many or any do. Try your example with any  $f(x)$ that satisfies the claimed identity instead of $x$.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind complex solutions, you can do it:  for any $b \ne 0$ take
$$ f(x) = b x,\ g(x) =  b \omega x$$
Thus 
$$ f^{-1}(x) = x/b, \ g^{-1}(x) = x/(b \omega)$$
and
$$ f(x) + g(x) = b (1+\omega) x, \ (f+g)^{-1}(x) = x/(b (1+\omega))$$
So $(f+g)^{-1} = f^{-1} + g^{-1}$ if
$$ \frac{1}{1+\omega} = 1 + \frac{1}{\omega} $$
which is true if $1 + \omega + \omega^2 = 0$.  The roots of this are $\omega = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{3} i}{2}$, the primitive cube roots of $-1$.

Comment: Thank you . So does it mean there is no real value solution?

Comment: We can leverage this to show is no real, differentiable solution with $f(0)=g(0)=0$.